# The Family tree of Lord Krishna

Tags: krishna, balarama

Please can someone help me with Sri Krishna and Balarama's family tree from Yayati to Krishna/Balrama's children, the wives/mothers, and any famous characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yayāti, is a king in Hindu tradition. He is described to be a Chandravamsha king. He is regarded to be the progenitor of the races of the Yadavas and the Pandavas.

His Consorts - Devayani ( daughter of Shukra, the Guru of Asuras), Sharmishtha ( daughter of Daitya King, Vrishaparvan

His Children - Yadu, Turvashu, Anudruhyu, Druhyu, Puru (Sons)
Madhavi (Daughter)

It is believed that Vrishni was the son of Satvata, a descendant of Yadu, the son of Yayati. He had two wives, Gandhari and Madri. He has a son named Devamidhusha by his wife Madri. Vasudeva, the father of Krishna was the grandson of Devamidhusha

Vasudeva had two sons Krishna, Balarama and a daughter Subhadra (mother - Devaki)

Krishna had 16108 wives of which 8 were queens, These 8 queens gave birth to 80 children

Rukmini: Charu, Charu Deshna, Charudeha, Charuchandra, Bhadracharu, Vicharu, Sudeshna, Sucharu, Charugupta, and Pradyumna.

Satyabhama: Bhanu, Swabhanu, Subhanu, Bhanumaan, Prabhanu, Atibhanu, Pratibhanu, Shribhanu, Bruhadbhanu, and Chandrabhanu.

Kalindi: Kavi, Subahu, Shanti, Purnamas, Vrush, Somak, Veer, Bhadra, Shrut, and Darsh.

Lakshmana: Prabal, Bal, Oja, Sah, Aparajit, Prabodh, Simha, Gatravaan, Mahashakti, and Urdhvag.

Bhadra: Satyak, Shoor, Arijit, Vaam, Jay, Aayu, Sangramjit, Praharan, Bruhatsen, and Subhadra.

Nagnajiti: Kunti, Vegavaan, Aam, Veer, Vasu, Ashwasen, Vrush, Shanku, Chandra, and Chitragu.

Jambavati: Vijay, Krutu, Samba, Sumitra, Dravin, Shatajit, Purujit, Vasuman, Shasrajit, and Chitraketu.

Mitravinda: Harsh, Kshudhi, Anand, Vruk, Mahash, Paavan, Anil, Varddhan, Vanhi, and Grudhra.

Samba: Lord Krishna’s most notorious son
One of his son named Samba has a very small role in the battle of Mahabharata. Most of the people resembled him as Lord Krishna, but Lord Krishna felt that he is more like Lord Shiva in many aspects.

Pradyumna: Ended the story of devil Sambara
He is another son of Lord Krishna who holds an interesting yet unknown story. It is said that he is the only power behind the death of Sambara. He cut off the head of Sambara with his sword. This is how he gathered some fame and recognition and this incident adds some new interesting facts of Krishna’s sons.

Pradyumna: Ended the story of devil Sambara

He is another son of Lord Krishna who holds an interesting yet unknown story. It is said that he is the only power behind the death of Sambara. He cut off the head of Sambara with his sword. This is how he gathered some fame and recognition and this incident adds some new interesting facts of Krishna’s sons.

Pradyumna married Rukmavati, had a child Anirudha

[image]

Balarama marries Revati,

Their Children :- Nishatha and Ulmuka(sons), Vatsala/Shashirekha (daughter)

Sources :- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayati
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrishni
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devayani
https://iskcondwarka.org/blogs/krishna-facts-80-sons-lord-krishna/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balarama
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniruddha
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna

These Wikipedia articles will help you a lot more to know the Family tree, I have just mentioned few from the vast family tree, You can know more by referring to the above Wikipedia articles